# Mock IRequestClient<> during Integration Testing using MassTransit

Tags: .net-core, nunit, moq, masstransit

I'm trying to do integration testing against a MediatR Command whose handler depends on an IRequestClient injected into its constructor.

```
    public class SayHelloCommand : IRequest<string>
    {
    }

    public class SayHelloCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<SayHelloCommand, string>
    {
        private readonly IRequestClient<IGetProfileMessageResult> _profileClient;

        public SayHelloCommandHandler(IRequestClient<IGetProfileMessageResult> profileClient)
        {
            _profileClient = profileClient;
        }
        public async Task<string> Handle(SayHelloCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var profile = (await _profileClient.GetResponse<IGetProfileMessageResult>(new {ProfileId = 1})).Message;

            return $"Hello {profile.FirstName}";
        }
    }
```

I've setup my test suite to use the InMemoryMassTransit but whenever I run my test it times out when it reaches the call using the IRequestClient<>. I've also tried to moq the IRequestClient to return a default response like this -

```
        [Test]
        public async Task ShouldSayHello()
        {
          
          
            var mockRequestClient = new Mock<IRequestClient<IGetProfileMessageResult>>();
            mockRequestClient.Setup(x => x.GetResponse<IGetProfileMessageResult>(It.IsAny<Object>(), default, default)
            .Result.Message).Returns(new GetProfileMessageResult
            {
                FirstName = "John"
            });

            serviceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IRequestClient<IGetProfileMessageResult>), mockRequestClient.Object));

            var result = await SendAsync(command);

            result.Status.Should().BeFalse();
            result.Message.Should().Contain("John");
        }
```

but this still times out.

Is there a way I can set up the InMemoryMassTransit to return a default response when the requestclient is called?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the in-memory test harness to setup a simple consumer that would respond to the request, instead of trying to mock `IRequestClient`. Though you should be able to mock it if you want, I just don’t know the syntax to properly configure your mock framework.

There are many samples using the test harness available, as well as all of the MassTransit unit tests.

Comment: So you mean I should just write a consumer in the same service that would respond to the IRequestClient client call and register it within the setup like x.Add.ConsumerTestHarness()? Can you point me to the samples you mentioned are available? By the way I'm using Moq